What does "son of Abraham" mean in Matthew 1:1

The book of the genealogy of Jesus Christ, the son of David, the son of Abraham.(Matt 1:1, ESV)

I have read a few commentaries and one suggests that "son of Abraham", indicates that Jesus is the ideal Jew, referencing(matt 3:9; 8:11-12). While the one I recently read say it indicates God's promise to Abraham to bless the families of the earth, meaning Christ is the fulfillment of that promise.

Now the Lord said[a] to Abram, “Go from your country[b] and your kindred and your father's house to the land that I will show you. 2 And I will make of you a great nation, and I will bless you and make your name great, so that you will be a blessing. 3 I will bless those who bless you, and him who dishonors you I will curse, and in you all the families of the earth shall be blessed.”(Gen 12:1-3, ESV).

which interpretation is it? or is it both?

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Yes! Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE Jelly. Glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out educating new users and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality answers. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

The pertinent noun here in Matt 1:1 is υἱός (huis) = "son" can take any of the following meanings:

biological (or rarely, adopted) son, eg, Luke 2:7
biological descendant by more than one generation; ie, grandson, great-grandson, or great-great (etc) grandson, eg, Matt 1:1, 20.
Spiritual son meaning one who follows the same spiritual path, ie, the equivalent of pupil, eg, 1 Peter 5:3

It is obvious that the meaning in Matt 1:1 and Matt 1:20 is "descendant of".  Matthew's purpose here in the opening of his gospel is to establish that Jesus is the rightful heir of Abraham and David and thus, that Jesus is both:

the promised Messiah as per the Abrahamic covenant, Gen 12:1-3, 13:14-17, 15:1-17, 17:1-27, 18:9-15, 22:15-18
the rightful king of Israel as per the Davidic covenant, 2 Sam 7, 23:5, 1 Kings 6:11, 12, 8:25, 1 Chron 17:11-14, 2 Chron 6:14-16, 7:17, 18, 13:5, Ps 89:4, 29, 34, 39, 132:11, 12, Jer 33:17, 21, Eze 37:15-28

